# Do Spikes kills trigger Slay effects?

Tags: monster-train

Some summons have a Slay effect: a benefit they gain whenever they score a kill. The Spikes effect on a summon causes enemies that attack the summon to take damage. If a foe dies to the Spikes damage of a summon that also has a Slay effect, does the Slay effect trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when an enemy dies because it attacked a unit with spikes it triggers Slay for that unit.

Same applies when an enemy has both spikes and a Slay effect and your own unit dies on its spikes.